# Python Tornado Request Handler Mapping

Tags: python, wsgi, tornado, web.py

I'm just getting started with Tornado and I was wondering how i can define a mapping so that all requests like below are are handled by a single handler.

1. /products/list
2. /products/find/123
3. /products/copy/123
4. /products/{action}/{argument1}/{argument2}/{argument3}

   > ```
   > class Application(tornado.web.Application):
   >     def __init__(self):
   >         handlers = [
   >             (r"/", home.HomeHandler),
   >             (r"/products/", product.ProductHandler)]
   >
   > class ProductHandler(base.BaseHandler):   
   >   def get(self, action, *args):
   >           self.write("Action:" + action + "<br>")
   >                 for arg in args:
   >                     self.write("argument:" + arg + "<br>")
   > ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't limited to listing a RequestHandler just once in the url matching, so you can do one of two things: Add a pattern explicitly matching each of the patterns you mention above like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    handlers = [
        (r"/", home.HomeHandler),
        (r"/products/list/([0-9]+)", product.ProductHandler)
        (r"/products/find/([0-9]+)", product.ProductHandler)
        (r"/products/copy/([0-9]+)", product.ProductHandler)
        (r"/products/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)", product.ProductHandler)]
```

Or you could say that "any URL that begins with "products" should be sent to the product handler," like so:

```
def __init__(self):
    handlers = [
        (r"/", home.HomeHandler),
        (r"/products/list/(.*)", product.ProductHandler)
```

and parse the variable list yourself in the ProductHandler.

Comment: If i use the pattern /products/list/(.*), where do i grab the variable list from ?

Comment: You can define your handler to accept an `args` parameter then parse as required. The captured pattern (i.e. anything after the /products/) will be available as `args`